# Getting Null Pointer when accessing a component from another Class

Tags: android

I have developed a class A which extends Dialog.

I have inflated the class A using the following code:

```
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_alert, null, false);
```

Within the `custom_alert` layout file , I have added an EditText with `android:id="@+id/edit"`.

The scenario is like this:

The user clicks on a specific `listitem` and a dialog opens where the user enters a value (Edit Text).

I have an Activity screen, consider class B which extends Activity.

From the class B, I am calling the class A.

When the user enters the value within the dialog and clicks on the button OK, I need to retrieve the value and store that in the database.

Providing the code snippet below

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);


EditText txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);

String value = txt.getText().toString();
```

But, even after inflating the `custom_dialog`, I am unable to fetch the text and I am getting null pointer exception.

I am pasting the update code ... still not getting the EditText value , only null

Dialog builder = new Dialog(this)

View view = LayoutInflater.from(SampleScreen.this).inflate(R.layout.custom_alert, null);
builder.setContentView(view);

EditText nameEditTxt = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit);

String value = nameEditTxt.getText().toString();

Answer (score 3):

`LayoutInflater#inflate` returns the inflated view, which you should call `findViewById` on.

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog, null);
EditText text = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edit);
```

Make sure to link this to the view hierarchy somehow:

```
dialog.setContentView(view);
```

or similar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , the null pointer exception is gone , but I am getting null for the data returned , while is incorrect . The data entered on the EditText is not getting fetched.                                                            EditText lapNameEditTxt = (EditText) view
          .findViewById(R.id.edit);
        String value = lapNameEditTxt.getText() .toString();

Comment: You have to call dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit) the second time. You can't inflate an entirely new view and expect to retrieve information about what is on the screen.

Comment: can you explain in detail .. dialog.findViewById(R.id.edit) to be called from where the second time .. would be nice if you paste pseudo/sample code ?

Comment: Sure. Where are you trying to call it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code snippet doesn't provide the context where it's called, but you also need to make sure it gets called from a context where the Android objects exist - not in your constructor for instance, but in one of the lifecycle methods for the Dialog (e.g. onCreate).

Comment: I *think* this would do fine in onCreateDialog using the Activity's context. At least, that's how I've been doing it.